# Reffering value from other cells in SUMIFS function

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007, sumifs

I need to use SUMIFS function in Excel 2007, currently my formula looks like this: 
=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,*"=string"*,c:c,"=E")

Now the value of *string* is placed inside cell A3 of sheet1.
Is there any way through which i can refer that value in SUMIFS formula like sheet1!$A$3

I try following code but it didn't work:

=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"=sheet1!$A$3",c:c,"=E")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you directly reference that cell without quotes? such as:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,sheet1!$A$3,c:c,"=E")
```